# Build .NET 1.1 in TFS 2010

Tags: msbee

As per [Microsoft Pattern & Practice blog](http://vstsguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20build%20a%20Microsoft%C2%AE%20.NET%201.1%20application%20with%20Team%20Build) its recommended to use MSBee.

To build a .NET 1.1 applications with Team Build

• Upgrade your .NET 1.1 solutions to .NET 2.0. You can do this by opening the solution in Visual Studio 2005 and running the Conversion Wizard, or by running devenv projectname /upgrade

• Ensure that the .NET 1.1 Software Development Kit (SDK) is installed on your build server.

• Download and install MSBuild Extras from http://www.codeplex.com/MSBee

• Download BuildingFx11inTB.targets from http://blogs.msdn.com/gautamg/attachment/578915.ashx

• Check out the build type from source control that will build your .NET 1.1 project.

• Copy BuildingFx11inTB.targets to the directory containing the build type and check the file into source control.

• Edit TFSBuild.proj file:

• Import the BuildingFx11inTB.targets file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\BuildingFx11inTB.targets" />
```

•Add a property defining the CSharp targets:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <AdditionalPropertiesForBuildTarget>
          CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets=$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\MSBee\MSBuildExtras.Fx1_1.CSharp.targets
     </AdditionalPropertiesForBuildTarget>  </PropertyGroup>
```

•Check TFSBuild.proj into source control.

But this will not work in TFS 2010 as there is no more TFSBuild.proj file. If MSBee is not possible and thru command line only .net 1.1 outputs need to be generated then how can we generate the .NET 1.1 complained output from VS 2010 IDE. It seems we need to specifically target VS 2003 MSBuild to generate 1.1 outputs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TFSBuild.proj file in TFS 2010 as long as you [use the UpgradeTemplate as the base for the build definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647553.aspx).

Comment: I am converting/upgrading my application to TFS 2010 and not upgrading frpm 2005/2008. Hence using TFSBuild.proj file from earlier version is not an option.